# Installed elementary on ubuntu 16.04. But no login screen now

Tags: 16.04, elementary

I installed elementary loki on ubuntu 16.04.3.  But after rebooting my login screen was on loop. Then removed gnome and unity. Now no login screen comes. I have installed pantheon-greeter. Any help for the gui?

Comment: Got login screen. But stuck in login loop now.

Comment: Please [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/995699/edit) your question and specify full steps to reproduce.

Comment: elementary OS is a separate operating system from Ubuntu. Did you install elementary OS on the same drive, erasing Ubuntu? Or did you manually add repositories and install packages?

Comment: I added the repositories and then installed elementary-desktop using apt-get